# Does HTTP content negotiation respect media type parameters

Tags: http, spring-mvc, content-negotiation

An HTTP request can include an `Accept` header, indicating the media type(s) of responses that the client will find acceptable. The server should honour the request by providing a response that has a `Content-Type` that matches (one of) the requested media type(s). A media type may include *parameters*. Does HTTP require that this process of content-negotiation respect *parameters*?

That is, if the client requests

```
 Accept: application/vnd.example; version=2
```

(here the `version` parameter has a value of `2`), and the server can serve media-type `application/vnd.example; version=1`, but not `application/vnd.example; version=2`, is it OK for the server to provide a response with

```
 Content-Type: application/vnd.example; version=1
```

Is it OK for the server to provide a response labelled

```
 Content-Type: application/vnd.example; version=2
```

but for the body of the response to actually be encoded as media-type `application/vnd.example; version=1`? That is, for the parameters of the media-type of a response to be an inaccurate description of the body of the response?

It seems that Spring MVC 4.1.0 does not respect media-type parameters when doing content negotiation, and gives responses for which the parameters of the media-type of the response are an inaccurate description of the body of the response. This seems to be because the `org.springframework.util.MimeType.isCompatibleWith(MimeType)` method does not examine the parameters of the `MimeType` objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant standard, [RFC 7231 section 3.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1), says the following about media-types:

> The type/subtype MAY be followed by parameters in the form of
> name=value pairs.

So, `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers may contain media type parameters. It adds:

> The presence or absence of a
> parameter might be significant to the processing of a media-type,
> depending on its definition within the media type registry.

That suggests that the server code that uses parameter types should pay attention to them, and not *simply* discard them, because for some media types they *will* be significant. It has to implement some smarts in whether to consider whether the media type parameters are significant.

Spring MVC 4.1.0 therefore seems to be wrong to completely ignore the parameters when doing content negotiation: the class `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` is incorrect to use `org.springframework.util.MimeType.isCompatibleWith(MimeType)`, or that `MimeType.isCompatibleWith(MimeType)` method is incorrect. If you provide Spring with several HTTP message converters that differ only in the parameters of their supported media type, Spring will not reliably choose the HTTP message converter that has the media type that exactly matches the requested media type.

---

In [section 3.1.1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5), where it describes the `Content-Type` header, it says:

> The indicated media type defines both the data
> format and how that data is intended to be processed by a recipient

As the parameters of a media type in general could vary the data format, the behaviour of Spring MVC 4.1.0 is wrong, in providing parameters that are an inaccurate description of the body of the response: the method `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.getMostSpecificMediaType(MediaType, MediaType)` is wrong to return the `acceptType` rather than the `produceTypeToUse` when the two types are equally specific.

---

However, [section 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4.1), which discusses content negotiation (*Proactive Negotiation*), notes:

> A user agent cannot rely on proactive negotiation preferences being
> consistently honored, since the origin server might not implement
> proactive negotiation for the requested resource or might decide that
> sending a response that doesn't conform to the user agent's
> preferences is better than sending a 406 (Not Acceptable) response.

So the server *is* permitted to give a response that does not *exactly* match the media-type parameters requested, as a fall-back when it can not provide an exact match. That is, it may choose to respond with a `application/vnd.example; version=1` response body, with a `Content-Type: application/vnd.example; version=1` header, despite the request saying `Accept: application/vnd.example; version=2`, *if, and only if* generating a valid `application/vnd.example; version=2` response would be impossible.

---

This apparently incorrect behaviour of Spring already has a Spring bug report, [SPR-10903](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10903). The Spring developers closed it as "Works as Designed", noting

> I don't know any rule for comparing media types with their parameters effectively. It really depends on the media type...If you're actually trying to achieve REST versioning through media types, it seems that the most common solution is to use different media types, since their format obviously changed between versions:

> - "`application/vnd.spring.foo.v1+json`"
> - "`application/vnd.spring.foo.v2+json`"

Comment: This is corrent. I've opened an issue with Spring, please go and vote for it to see the appropriate changes approved. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17133

Answer (score 3):

The relevant spec for content negotiation in HTTP/1.1 is [RFC2616, Section 14.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.1).

It contains the following example, relevant to your question:

```
Accept: text/*, text/html, text/html;level=1, */*
```

and gives the precedence as

```
1) text/html;level=1
2) text/html
3) text/*
4) */*
```

So I think it is safe to say that `text/html;level=1` and `text/html` are different media types.
I would also consider `text/html;level=1` and `text/html;level=2` as different.

So in your example I think it would be correct to respond with a 406 error and not respond with a different media type.