# 5 levels of media type Spring REST

Tags: spring, rest, domain-driven-design, cqrs, media-type

I am trying to apply CQRS principles on my REST API with domain-driven-design principles, using the 5 levels of Media Types, as explained in these articles:
https://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-api-on-cqrs
http://byterot.blogspot.ch/2012/12/5-levels-of-media-type-rest-csds.html

My technical context is Spring REST framework version 3.2.

Basically, i need to be able to map my commands using different "domain-model" media types.
Therefore, i would expect the following mapping to work:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("resources")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json;domain-model=CommandOne")
    @ResponseBody
    public void commandOne(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody CommandOne commandOne) {
        LOG.info("Using command {}", commandOne);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json;domain-model=CommandTwo")
    @ResponseBody
    public void commandTwo(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody CommandTwo commandTwo) {
        LOG.info("Using command {}", commandTwo);
    }

}
```

Problem is, I am getting mapping errors when requesting for a PUT:

```
PUT /resources/123
Content-Type: application/json;domain-model=CommandOne
```

Error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path ...
```

Spring doesn't allow me to map the same uri the different domain-model Media Types. Any idea how could I achieve that? Am I missing something?

Many thanks
:o)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the content-type is still the same `application/json`. Please look at Content-Type [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)
What you are passing as `domain-model=CommandOne` is just a parameter and Spring doesn't recognize as a difference to call the different methods.

This is described in more detail on answer
[Does HTTP content negotiation respect media type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071006/does-http-content-negotiation-respect-media-type-parameters)

This was submitted as a [BUG](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10903) to the Spring team but they closed with "Work as designed".

Unfortunately Spring can't treat this case currently.